# SyntaxError: Unexpected token o in JSON at position 1 when get rails json

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json, webpack, vuejs2, axios

Hi when i tried to search in my rails application (is not api mode) I work with rails 5 , webpacker and vue

in my controller this is my code

```
def search_information_sources
 text = params[:text]
 @list_books = Book.where('title ILIKE ?', "#{text}%").limit(10)
 render json: @list_books
end
```

In my vue component i call the promise

```
    const token = document.querySelector('meta[name="csrf-token"]').getAttribute('content');
    axios.get("/syllabuses/search_information_sources", {
      authenticity_token: token,
      text: "negocios"
    })
    .then(function (response) {
      console.log(response.data);
      this.items_basic = JSON.parse(response.data);
    })
    .catch(function (error) {
      alert(error);
      toastr.error("No se pudo procesar la solicitud,  " + error.response.data.message_error);
    });
```

But when i execute this code i receive the error

This is my log in rails

```
Started GET "/syllabuses/search_information_sources.json" for ::1 at 2019-01-02 11:03:00 -0500
11:03:00 backend.1  | Processing by SyllabusesController#search_information_sources as JSON
11:03:00 backend.1  |   User Load (3.6ms)  SELECT  "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."id" = $1 ORDER BY "users"."id" ASC LIMIT $2  [["id", 1], ["LIMIT", 1]]
11:03:00 backend.1  |   ↳ app/controllers/application_controller.rb:32
11:03:00 backend.1  |   Book Load (1.0ms)  SELECT  "books".* FROM "books" WHERE (title ILIKE '%') LIMIT $1  [["LIMIT", 10]]
11:03:00 backend.1  |   ↳ app/controllers/syllabuses_controller.rb:143
11:03:00 backend.1  | Completed 200 OK in 48ms (Views: 16.8ms | ActiveRecord: 4.6ms)
```

Comment: where are you getting this error ?, is it happening in your controller ? or in your javascript code ?. It seems to be happening in your controller, if so, do you mind posting the Rails log of your request/response ?, are there any `before_filter`s running in your controller ?.

Comment: Hi fanta, i added my logs in my answer . The error i received when i print the error catch with alert(error) I dont have a before_filter for this action..

Comment: So it looks like your controller code is fine. Put a `debugger` in your `then` function before the `console.log` and see what you get there, try to execute the `JSON.parse(response.data)` line by hand and see if that causes the error.

Comment: I think you don't have to use `JSON.parse`. from the axios docs: `JSON responses are automatically parsed.`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solution this problem, the problem is the context

```
var _that = this;
```

I use var _that = this; before call de promise and inside the then i use

```
_that.items_basic =response.data;
```

The final code for my javascript is

```
var _that = this;
const token = document.querySelector('meta[name="csrf-token"]').getAttribute('content');
let resultado = [];
axios.get("/syllabuses/search_information_sources.json", {
  authenticity_token: token,
  params: {text_filter: text}
})
.then(function (response) {
  console.log(response.data);
  _that.items_basic = response.data;
})
.catch(function (error) {
  alert(error);
  toastr.error("No se pudo procesar la solicitud,  " + error.response.data.message_error);
});
```